# Click() or Submit() is not working for Selenium java code

Tags: java, javascript, html, selenium, automation

I am trying to enter the text in a search box and click on text should open the links under it.
So far i am able to enter the text in search box but enter or click or submit is not recognized. Ideally if we enter text and click enter, it should display the elements within the search text.

Webdriver code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wd, 100);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("span16"))‌​);

WebElement signupForm = wd.findElement(By.className("span16"));
signupForm.sendKeys("MTestin");

WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(wd, 100);
wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("omedia-s‌​earch"))).click();
```

Page HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid sort-text">
    <input id="searchbox" class="span16" type="text" placeholder="showing all result" data-provide="typeahead" name="input" />
    <i class="omedia-search"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't post the code as comments, add it to the question.

Comment: Can you elaborate the steps? Your question is not so much under-stable.

Comment: `<input />` should be a single html tag

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the `click` on the `wait.until...`, not on the element itself.

You need to do a `wd.findElement` for the button too, just like you did it for the search box.

Also, I think it is safe to assume that the page is fully loaded once the first `wait` call is done, so there's no need to wait to find the button too.

Here is how I would do it:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wd, 100);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("span16"))‌​);

WebElement signupForm = wd.findElement(By.className("span16"));
signupForm.sendKeys("MTestin");

WebElement submitButton = wd.findElement(By.className("omedia-s‌​earch"));
submitButton.click();
```

---

Parenthetically, you aren't searching on very good terms - the class `span16` is structural so it may appear in other places if the page design changes.  Instead, search for the `id` of the field, because that is guaranteed to be unique on a properly-built page.

Comment: Hi, Hope you can help me. When i entr "Mtesting" into the search box, a drop down suggestion list (Like when we do google search a dropdown of suggested elelments occur) will come. I should click in that dropdown. That is how the developer has coded it. By just entering into the search box and calling the Click() method is not functioning. 
If that is not possible other way to do it is by clicking one of the options present as <Li> elements. Pls help the code is below
<div>

    <span class="text">

        Zovi

    </span>
    <span class="icon off omedia-right-open pull-right"></span>

Comment: @AutoMationBegginer what autocompletion library is being used?  Or, if it is autocompletion code that was written for this project specifically (instead of using a library), please post it.  There are likely several ways to trigger choosing an option, but the only way to know is to see what code is being used to create the dropdown.